# How can we convert CAD schematic diagrams to ArcGIS geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, cad

I have been working on an assignment where I am supposed to convert some CAD schematic diagrams to GIS features and load them to a Geo database.
Had it been a simple cad file (non schematic) I could do it using CADtoGeodatabase_conversion tool available in arcgis. However I am not sure if the same approach would work for the CAD schematic diagrams.
If anyone has tried it in the past or knows of any tool which could be helpful in this case then please let me know.

Comment: You can add CAD files to Arcmap by going to add data. From there I suggest selecting the layers/features you are interested in and export them to GDB.

Comment: What have *you* tried?